# Scala List unpacking with colon colon syntax case sensitivity

Tags: list, scala, case-sensitive

I'm wondering about a weird issue with compilation results for list unpacking using the `::` syntax. From what I've tested, the compilation result depends on the case of the first letter, and I am trying to figure out why:
(I've added the log from the scala REPL)

```
scala> val smallExample :: Nil = (0 until 1).toList // works
val smallExample: Int = 0

scala> val CapitalExample :: Nil = (0 until 1).toList // fails with compile error
           ^
       error: not found: value CapitalExample
```

I wanted to use this syntax to build something that resembles a C Enum without having to specify all indices manually, but I'd need ALL_CAPS_UNDERSCORE  to adhere to the naming convention.

Do you have input on alternatives without having to specify all constants (32 at least) or ignoring the naming convention?

To elaborate my usage: I'm trying to build a small RISC-V CPU in Chisel, and I needed all the opcodes in a list from 0 to 31:
`LOAD :: LOAD_FP :: CUSTOM_1 :: MISC_MEM :: ... :: RESERVED_80BIT :: Nil = (0 until 32).toList`, and obviously I do not want to specify all those numbers explicitly.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand why you need to use this syntax though. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I've tried parenthesis around the whole statement and the name itself, to no avail. RE usage, I've edited the question

Comment: You'll have to write the 32 variable names anyway, I don't see much value in doing this rather than 32 distinct variables. You could also use regular Java enums with their ordinal value.

Comment: In pattern matching a capital, case means that you want to match a constant that already exists. That is what allows you to match `Nil` at the end instead of that creating a new variable.

Comment: for the first case, that means I'd have to repeat all numbers which would violate the DRY principle, and for using the ordinals clutters the code very much, as those numbers are needed often

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a pattern match (a destructuring assignment is a special case of a pattern match), both variable and constant matches are possible:

```scala
match {
  case x => ???    // a variable match
  case Nil => ???  // a constant match (not actually reachable)
}
```

In order to disambiguate these cases, the language specification sets out a rule that a simple name starting with a lowercase letter is a variable, and any other simple name is interpreted as a constant.

The language spec calls for a simple name starting with a lowercase letter to be treated as a constant if it is  enclosed in backticks:

```scala
val pi = 3.14
math.E match {
  case `pi` => "Strange math?"
  case _ => "Seems OK"
}
```

The language spec does not include a way to force a simple name starting with a non-lowercase letter to be interpreted as a variable in a pattern match.